# Drag and drop text from a JLabel to JTable using transferHandler

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, jlabel

I was following the below mentioned tutorial. Under topic [Extending Default DnD Support](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/uiswing/misc/dnd.html) of this tutorial there is an application with a `JTextArea`, a `JList` and a `JTable`.

And it works perfectly. In addition I used a `JLabel`. I set the transfer handler of this label as:

```
jLabel1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
```

When I dragged this label onto the table, it doesn't accept it. But it works for the string from the text area.

How can I drag and drop text from the label on to a table?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new TransferHandler("text");
```

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html
>
> This class is implemented to provide a default behavior of transferring a component property simply by specifying the name of the property in the constructor. For example, to transfer the foreground color from one component to another either via the clipboard or a drag and drop operation a TransferHandler can be constructed with the string "foreground". The built in support will use the color returned by getForeground as the source of the transfer, and setForeground for the target of a transfer.

`JTable` has not `setText(String)` method. So you would need to override the `TransferHander#importData(...)` method to import the data into the cell of the `JTable`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DnDTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JTable table = new JTable(5, 3);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    table.setTransferHandler(new ToTransferHandler());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
    label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
        c.getTransferHandler().exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
      }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    p.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new DnDTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

//@see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dropactiondemo.html
class ToTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
  @Override public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
    return getPropertyDataFlavor(String.class, support.getDataFlavors()) != null;
  }
  @Override public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
    // if we can't handle the import, say so
    if (!canImport(support)) {
      return false;
    }

    DataFlavor flavor = getPropertyDataFlavor(String.class, support.getDataFlavors());

    // fetch the data and bail if this fails
    String data;
    try {
      data = (String) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(flavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | java.io.IOException e) {
      return false;
    }

    JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
    JTable table = (JTable) support.getComponent();
    table.setValueAt(data, dl.getRow(), dl.getColumn());
    return true;
  }
  //@see TransferHandler.java private DataFlavor getPropertyDataFlavor(...) {
  private DataFlavor getPropertyDataFlavor(Class<?> k, DataFlavor[] flavors) {
    for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
      DataFlavor flavor = flavors[i];
      if ("application".equals(flavor.getPrimaryType()) &&
          "x-java-jvm-local-objectref".equals(flavor.getSubType()) &&
          k.isAssignableFrom(flavor.getRepresentationClass())) {
        return flavor;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped me neat! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to manually add a mouse event handler to the label to do this:

```
jLabel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
    JComponent comp = (JComponent) evt.getSource();
    TransferHandler th = comp.getTransferHandler();

    th.exportAsDrag(comp, evt, TransferHandler.COPY);
  }
});
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingDragandDropSupporttoaJLabelComponent.htm

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention it. I have done that.